# eConnect to Great Plains Error: 'Timeout expired' - How to fix?

Tags: .net, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp, econnect

Receiving the following error when trying to pull reconciled orders from the last 30 days in Great Plains from a SOAP call:

> Server</faultcode><faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
>   Server was unable to process request.
>   ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Timeout expired.  The timeout period
>   elapsed prior to completion of the
>   operation or the server is not
>   responding.
>    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean
>   breakConnection)
>    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)

How can I determine or change the timeout setting? Is that a connection string variable? In our web service method, it has this at the beginning:

```
ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gp"].ToString();
```

Which it gets from a web.config file:

```
<configuration>

    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="gp" connectionString="Data Source=10.10.10.90;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;trusted_connection=true;Initial Catalog=DEFAULT;" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
```

Not all that versed in ASP/eConnect and this has worked up until a few weeks ago when the timeout error started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing the amount of records returned to 15 days seems to alleviate this issue.